# Finding Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla dll in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'm not able to find **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XMLA.dll** that I need to import

```
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla;
```

I have found some articles and answered questions for SQL Server 2005 and 2012. But nothing works for me in the 2008 R2 version. My SQL Server/Analysis services is installed with all features enabled as far as I can tell and still there is no dll with the name I want anywhere on my computer. I don't need a redistributable solution because all computers using this product will have a full SSAS installation on them.

This thread adresses the same problem but without any useable answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/84f06276-208a-48e8-be88-b6bdc24406d6

Do I need to install something extra or did I miss it in some way? No it is not in \windows\assembly\gac_msil\microsoft.analysisservices.xmla.dll as the reply in the above forum post suggests.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, for sql server 2005 this Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XMLA.dll is (part?) of Analysis Services OLE DB Provider. It should be available in [Feature Pack for Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24793).

For SQL Server 2008 R2, Microsoft thinks you should use AMOMD to query AS database... :(

Comment: FWIW, I have only ever had 2008 R2 on my home machine here (install has SSIS and 2 DB engine instances, no SSAS), and I do have that assembly in my GAC.

Comment: Ozren: Yes thank you. I was able to solve my problem with AMOMD. But I did not have the amomd dll in my system so I imported it in an ugly way. Still have to find the correct installer for that if you can help me.